# Does Windows 8 Surface support stolen device tracking?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface

I recently had my home robbed and all my computers stolen. Now I have a new Windows 8 Surface tablet, and I would like to track and recover it if it is stolen or lost. Is this possible?

Comment: There is something called the Prey Project, which (probably) uses Wi-Fi connectivity to announce to an owner that their stolen device has been found. Check it out, but take careful note that it probably won't run on Windows RT.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Surface doesn't have GPS I would have my doubts :-)

Comment: See my comment above. There is a number of wi-fi-enabled "I found it!" services around, but I think the bigger issue is whether they're compatible with Windows RT.

Answer (score 1):

There are no *official* Microsoft applications that let you do that, however it is likely that there will be [3rd party apps](http://preyproject.com/) that fill that gap, just like those that appeared for windows phones, laptops etc.

Since it doesn't have GPS, it'd have to rely on [wifi positioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system), which would make it untrackable easily if the thief knows what they're doing.

Comment: " which would make it untrackable easily if the thief knows what they're doing." Or if they re-install the OS, or delete the tracking program, but then most thieves of this caliber are not too smart.