# Locate stolen surface tablet

Tags: windows-8, security

Similar to this older question [Does Windows 8 Surface support stolen device tracking?](https://superuser.com/questions/494824/does-windows-8-surface-support-stolen-device-tracking), but I'd like to locate my already stolen tablet, and the reason I have some hope is...

When I viewed my Microsoft account settings just now, under "My apps" it lets you see which apps are installed on "your devices".  In the dropdown list of "my devices" it has one with a name that I've never used/owned.  When I select the name, I see a list of all of the apps I had installed on my old/stolen tablet.

From what I can tell they haven't installed any new apps... so that might be a sign they aren't using my account anymore.  But they must have renamed the tablet while it was still linked to my account.

Anyone have any inside knowledge about what tracking/log info Microsoft might have that would help the police?  Or any type of access log for my account that I can check, to tell me where (or IP addresses) my account has been used?  I'm not sure I want to just take my new tablet in and say "hey, look at this, does this help?" -- I have a feeling they'll just give me some "we'll look in to it, or no" type answer.. but if I can give them some specific info/details maybe that would help?

I don't really care about the money/value... just hate thieves, and always try to catch them when I can (have on a couple occasions).

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/account/security/recentactivity.aspx  might have helped, too bad it was stolen 3 months ago, and the log only has 30 days.. maybe someone knows from experience if Microsoft actually has more saved, "just in case"?

Comment: Unless you had tracking software on it.  Its doubtful we can suggest.  Even if we did they would have have to gain access to your account.